# aiogram-calendar проблемы с кодирвокой, крякозябры

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram-3.x, calendar, codepage

Удалось прикрутить aiogram-calendar по документации https://github.com/noXplode/aiogram_calendar, все как бы работает ... если бы не одно но ... В общем когда запускаю код из среды ide (PyCharm) и нажимаю на вывод календаря - все выводит замечательно, кириллица все ок
https://disk.yandex.ru/i/ASdCp8MOcoApuQ

а вот когда я код скомпилировал в исполняемый exe (через pyinstaller), то потом когда проверяю календарь - там вместо кириллицы крякозябры:
https://disk.yandex.ru/i/0JTizwSoNf1YIQ

Кто знает как исправить?

Comment: А зачем телеграм бот запаковать в .ехе вообще..? Это какой-то особый вид извращенства?

Comment: пока видимо да .. бот еще в разработке ... есть ноут с ide на котором пишу \ тестирую ... есть свободный комп на win10, на котором запускаю beta версию бота :-) и смотрю как он в долгосрочной перспективе себя ведет ... или ботов надо как то иначе запускать? буду благодарен есть подскажете примерно как, что почитать...

Comment: У вас есть исходники, скопировали на свой комп, установили зависимости - запустили

Comment: Да согласен ... не правильно я это все запускал. Сделал как Вы сказали, и все заработало как надо ... спасибо. Проблема с кодировкой пропала. Красота.